# How to set child li attribute based on the parent li attribute using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have the menu structure like below,

```
<div class="submenu">
<ul class="treeview">
  <li class="submenu" id="menu-item-5592" style="background-image: url('open.gif');">
     <a href="/Products/Category/Large-Custom-Water-Features">Large Custom Water Features</a>   
     <ul class="sub-menu" rel="open" style="display: block;">          
       <li class="submenu" >
         <ul class="submenu" rel="closed" style="disply:none;">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>          
         </ul>
       </li>       
     </ul>    
  </li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

In the above menu the whole li has `style="background-image: url('open.gif');"`. previously it was `style="background-image: url('closed.gif');"`.

the above attribute set when i clicked that link. i need when i click that link the i needt to change display attribute from `<ul class="submenu" rel="closed" style="display:none;">` to `<ul class="submenu" rel="closed" style="display:block;">`

how can i do this?

Comment: so the `a href='/Products/Category/Large-Custom-Water-Features'` should show the `ul li` but not the `ul` within the `ul li` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very concrete answer to your problem, but more a suggestion:

Instead of dealing with `style` attributes, I would add/remove a class to each `<li>` element like `close`, `open` (or re-use the `rel` attribute you already have) and then solve your issue just with CSS.

This separates logical concerns (you only change an abstract open/close state) from the visual representation of these states.

jQuery supports this approach very well.